# Disable Mobile Menu, (always show desktop menu)

Tags: menus

I’m having trouble with something.

I have a (almost) one page website with only my logo in the header/top-bar but no other menu items. But when i see my site on a mobile device it does switch to a mobile menu (hamburger menu) and i dont want that preferably. I always want to show my header/top-bar like it is on desktop version with only my logo in it. I have tried a lot but havent found how to do this.
Any suggestions?
Thank you for the effort!
Bye.

Theme: Gateway (https://rescuethemes.com/wordpress-themes/gateway/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your browser, hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to inspect your mobile menu.  If you resize your browser between 640px & 641px you can see the different styles being applied.  You just need to override the styles for mobile.

Here is what I came up with.  Paste these styles in `Admin > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS`.

```
.top-bar .title-area {
    float: left  !important;
}

section.top-bar-section {
    display: inline-block !important;
}    

.top-bar-section li.active:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
    padding: 0 21.66667px  !important;
    line-height: 65px  !important; 
}
```

Comment: Holy Cow you did it! thank you so much! Can i write a review about you or help you with something? I'm new here so i dont know exactly how to tank you.... Cheers from Amsterdam.

Comment: No problem.  Typically all you need to do is upvote and/or accept the answer.